# There is still shown 1 item left after i deleted all the list of items. How to fix this?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, android-recyclerview

im new here and i also begginer in android development.
Everything is work exepct this one. Technically delete item is also works. but when i deleted the last one item, it removed on the database but still shown in the activity(it's gone when i restart the app after deleting it)

Here is my code:
**Here is the problem**
[Before i delete the last item on the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynS5Z.png)
[After I delete the last item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fp2I.png)

**Here is my repository**

```
private val mWebsDao: WebDao
    private val executorService: ExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

init {
        val db = WebRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        mWebsDao = db.webDao()
    }

fun deleteWeb(web: Web) {
        executorService.execute { mWebsDao.deleteWebById(web) }
    }
```

**Here is my ViewModel**

```
private val mWebRepository: WebRepository = WebRepository(application)

fun deleteWeb(web: Web) {
        mWebRepository.deleteWeb(web)
    }
```

**Here is MyAdapter**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val (_, webName, webUrl, webImgColor) = listWeb[position]

        holder.binding.imgColorWeb.background = ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.rgb(webImgColor.r, webImgColor.g, webImgColor.b))
        holder.binding.tvWebName.text = webName
        holder.binding.tvWebLink.text = webUrl
        holder.binding.tvCharWebName.text = webName

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(listWeb[holder.adapterPosition])
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            val popUpMenu = PopupMenu(holder.itemView.context, holder.itemView)
            popUpMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup_item_pressed)

            popUpMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
                when (menuItem.itemId) {
                    R.id.action_edit -> {
                        onItemLongClickCallback.onItemLongClickedEdit(listWeb[holder.adapterPosition])
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.action_delete -> {
                        onItemLongClickCallback.onItemLongClickedDelete(listWeb[holder.adapterPosition])
                        notifyItemRemoved(holder.adapterPosition)
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }

            popUpMenu.show()
            true
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listWeb.size

    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(web: Web)
    }

    interface OnItemLongClickCallback {
        fun onItemLongClickedEdit(web: Web)
        fun onItemLongClickedDelete(web: Web)
    }
```

**Here is MyActivity**

```
override fun onItemLongClickedDelete(web: Web) {
                        mainViewModel.deleteWeb(web)

                        Snackbar.make(binding.root, getString(R.string.deleted_web_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction(getString(R.string.undo)) {
                                mainViewModel.insertWeb(web)
                            }
                            .show()
                    }
```

show the list ini activity

```
 mainViewModel.getAllWebs().observe(this) {
            if (it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                binding.emptyListInfo.alpha = 1f
            } else {
                binding.emptyListInfo.alpha = 0f
                val webs = webList(it)
                val rvWeb = binding.rvListWeb
                rvWeb.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                webAdapter = WebAdapter(webs)
                rvWeb.adapter = webAdapter
```

[want this without restart the app after deleteing the item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLwyl.png)

Comment: Can you show the code for your `viewModel.getAllWebs()` function, and if it calls something in your repo and then your DAO, show those, too?

Comment: You don't actually delete the item from your adapter's data set, so when you call `notifyItemRemoved` it's still there. So you're relying on the `long click callback -> viewModel.deleteWeb` event to generate an update to some data that you're observing, so the adapter is given a new set of data to display (i.e. the list, but with the deleted item removed). Since it's working for everything *except the last item*, the problem is probably that your observer checks if the list is empty, and *doesn't update the adapter* if that's true. You'd be better pushing the current data every time

Comment: @Tenfour04 , `fun getAllWebs(): LiveData<List<Web>> = mWebRepository.getAllWebs()`

Comment: @cactustictacs , Thank you for your help. I solved that now with your advice